# Why are methods created outside the main method not able to function inside a RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

```
singleRDD:RDD[(String)]
val xRDD = singleRDD.map(e=>{
  func1(e.dest)
})
val xIterator = singleRDD.collectAsMap().map(e => {
  func1(e.dest)
})
def func1(str:String):String = {
   //some logic
   var str = "what I want"
   str
}
```

in terms of this comparison, xRDD contains nothing while xIterator contains what I want. func1 is established outside the main method.
so why does this phoenomenon emerge? how do I address this issue?
Thank you for your hints!

Comment: Why do you think "xRDD contains nothing"?

Comment: What is `dest` in your code?

Comment: I had debugged the code and found out xRDD contains nothing. func1 is to deal with a string of e.dest and return a new string.